# How to get the server address of the ArcGIS lyr. file

Tags: qgis, wfs, layer-file

I have a lyr. file and want use the content in QGIS. So my question is how can I check where this lyr. linked to. I don't need the style just want data itself.

Comment: Do you have access to ArcGIS Desktop, and therefore arcpy, with which to read the contents of the *.lyr file?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I don't have much experience with code.  Is this the only way? What the code looks like to read the lyr. data source? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import arcpy
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"\\path\to\layer\file")
datasource = lyr.dataSource
print datasource
```

You mentioned that you have ArcGIS (in the comments).

Using arcpy, the above code will list the datasource the layer file is referencing.  You can use this through the python window in ArcMap or as a stand alone script.

UPDATE: If you would rather not use python, you can simply open the layer file in ArcMap and view the properties of the layer.  There is a 'Source' tab in the properties that displays the location of the data.

UPDATE2:  You need to either escape the slashes in your filepath or specify it as a raw string by prefixing with r (i.e. r"\temp\test.lyr")

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I run the script it returns this error message: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 429, in __init__
    super(LayerMixin, self).__init__(lyrfile)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 47, in __init__
    for arg in args))
ValueError: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source
do you know what's going wrong thanks

Comment: it looks like the layer file has an invalid datasource.  Have you opened it in ArcMap to see if it references an existing dataset?  You may need to fix the datasource in arc and re-save the layer file.

Comment: try putting an r in front of the path to the layer:  lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"\\file\path\layer.lyr").  I've tested this in ArcMap and Python command line and both work.

Comment: I just verified that you need to put an 'r' in front of the filepath.  I just tested it without the r and I got the same error you did.